# Reading date only with PL/SQL from datetime field , from informix database

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, informix

I am having problem reading only the date with PL/SQL. The field that i want to read is datetime and its name is last_updated. I am doing comparation between oracle and informix databases and thats why i am using pl/sql. 
I have a query that looks and must work and its like this:

```
        select to_date("last_updated", 'dd/mm/YYYY')   from "smetka"@informix
```

This query is returning results, and it dont gives any error, but the format of the date is like this 30.06.**0**014 and must be 30.06.**2**014

Comment: can you check numeric value? It sounds crazy but maybe the date is really 0014?

Comment: @are It is more likely that the `last_updated` column has the value `30/06/14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably find that the database expected the date to be entered using the format `dd/mm/yyyy` but whatever application deposited used the format `dd/mm/yy` and trying to format it using `dd/mm/yyyy` the database just accepts it as being in the 1st century (rather than as expected the 21st century).

For example:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '30/06/14', 'dd/mm/yy' )   AS date1,
       TO_DATE( '30/06/14', 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) AS date2
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

```
DATE1               DATE2
------------------- -------------------
2014-06-30 00:00:00 0014-06-30 00:00:00
```

You could try to correct it using something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN TO_DATE( "last_updated", 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
              BETWEEN DATE '0000-01-01' AND DATE 0100-01-01'
       THEN TO_DATE( "last_updated", 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) + INTERVAL '2000' YEAR(4)
       ELSE TO_DATE( "last_updated", 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
       END
FROM   "smetka"@informix
```

or

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( "last_updated", '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}' )
       THEN TO_DATE( "last_updated", 'dd/mm/yy' )
       ELSE TO_DATE( "last_updated", 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
       END
FROM   "smetka"@informix
```