# How To Fetch Data Between 2 Dates In Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle's SQL . I want to fetch data between 2 dates .

Date is in this format in DB : **13-DEC-10**

This is the query I have written :

```
SELECT SUM(total_amount) 
  FROM table a
 WHERE trn_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(01-APR-17, 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
   AND TO_DATE(31-MAR-17, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ;
```

But its giving me error . How to proceed next ?

Comment: The first date should be before the second date. If you have errors, you should also post the error details/message.

Comment: Hey Andy ! Thanks for the suggestion . I managed to resolve it .

Answer (score 4):

A date does not have a format - it is [stored internally to the database as 7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) (representing year, month, day, hour, minute and second) and it is not until whatever user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc) tries to display it to you, the user, and converts it into something you would find meaningful (usually a string) that the date has a format.

To fix your query you just need to surround the date string in single quotes and to use `YY` to match the 2-digit year format (otherwise Oracle will assume that `17` in the format `YYYY` is the year `0017` and the [century will not be as you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585337/1509264)):

```
select sum(TOTAL_AMOUNT)
from   table a
where  trn_date between TO_DATE('01-APR-17', 'DD-MON-YY')
                    AND TO_DATE('31-MAR-17', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

However, you can also use date literals (and skip having to match the date format model):

```
select sum(TOTAL_AMOUNT)
from   table a
where  trn_date between DATE '2017-04-01'
                    AND DATE '2017-05-31';
```

Comment: If you are using to use only 2 digits for the year then I think `RR` would be the better format.

Comment: Hi @MTO. In your query, I try to bind the date range-    `where effDate BETWEEN DATE :fromDate AND DATE :toDate`                                  
 But I get 'ORA-00936: missing expression'  Error. How do I bind the range?

Comment: @satyaprakashPanigrahi `select sum(TOTAL_AMOUNT) from table a where trn_date between :range_start AND :range_end` (assuming that you are binding `DATE` values to bind variables, if not then you need to provide a [MRE] but, for string bind values, you would probably just wrap the bind variable in `TO_DATE(:range_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` and modify the format model as appropriate).

Comment: @MTO, my binding is a String type, so using 2nd suggestion & it's working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you may use the year format of `RR` format against centurial problems, Don't forget to keep quotes for date values, and you may prefer calling sql with bind variables :

```
SELECT SUM(total_amount) 
  FROM table a
 WHERE trn_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('&date_1', 'DD-MON-RR') 
   AND TO_DATE('&date_2', 'DD-MON-RR') ; --> where date_1 is 31-MAR-17  
                                         --    and date_2 is 01-APR-17 in your case.
```

What I mentioned by centurial problems :

> ***The RR Datetime Format Element***
>
> The RR datetime format element is similar to the YY datetime format
> element, but it provides additional flexibility for storing date
> values in other centuries. The RR datetime format element lets you
> store 20th century dates in the 21st century by specifying only the
> last two digits of the year.
>
> If you use the TO_DATE function with the YY datetime format element,
> then the year returned always has the same first 2 digits as the
> current year. If you use the RR datetime format element instead, then
> the century of the return value varies according to the specified
> two-digit year and the last two digits of the current year.
>
> That is:
>
> If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then
>
> If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the
> returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.
>
> If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the
> first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 greater than the first 2
> digits of the current year.
>
> If the specified two-digit year is 50 to 99, then
>
> If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the
> first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 less than the first 2 digits
> of the current year.
>
> If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the
> returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.